# azure app logic condition help needed

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am exploring Azure App Logic. I defined actions to read data from Google spread sheet using "Get Rows".

Now I want to access only  records with a defined condition based on one of the columns in spreadsheet.

I have tried multiple approaches to do that. What I found is that the filter query option in "Get Rows" is not implemented. Then I started looking at "Add condition" to define a condition.

I have used conditions like

> @equals(item()['Processed'], '1')

But nothing is working. And the condition is always failing. Please suggest how to define a condition here.

Best Regards
Krishna G

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest schema of Logic Apps (2016-06-01), then you can use the 'Query' action type to filter the list.

In the below sample, 'Get_rows' is the action that reads data from a spreadsheet

```
"Query_rows": {
    "type": "Query",
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@body('Get_rows').value",
        "where": "@equals(item()['Processed'], 1)"
    },
    "runAfter": { "Get_rows": [ "Succeeded" ] }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I am unable to see the 'Query' action. And I recently a month back subscribed to this. I also tried to update schema. But the option is disabled. Please suggest.

Comment: I can see an action called "Filter Array". I changed it as per the spec you have suggested. But I am getting the following message: {"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"The execution of template action 'Query_rows' failed: The evaluation of 'query' action 'where' expression '@equals(triggerBody()['Proessed'], 1)' failed: 'The template language expression 'equals(triggerBody()['Proessed'], 1)' cannot be evaluated because property 'Proessed' cannot be selected. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'."}.  Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Just to update you, even though I am using item(),azure is automatically updating it as triggerBody(). If I use a incorrect column, I am getting message as no column exist. If I am using the right column, I am getting the above mentioned message. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Any further suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: Any help please? I am kind of struck here for more than 2 weeks. Your guidance will be very very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Any further help please. I a helpless as no one is able to answer this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a typo in your expression? 'Proessed' should be spelled 'Processed'. The automatic change of item() to triggerBody() is a known bug that will be addressed in the current week. If you save your definition with @item(), then it should run correctly. You can also use resources.azure.com to verify that the definition is what you expect.

Comment: When you get a 'property cannot be selected' error message, then you can inspect what properties are available by reviewing the outputs of the trigger. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-monitor-your-logic-apps/ for more details